# Fetch files parallelly from an SFTP server using AWS ECS tasks using Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, sftp, amazon-ecs

I want to write a lambda that:

- connect to an SFTP server
- creates an ECS instance that spins parallel fargate tasks
- fargate task to copy each file into an aws s3 location.

these are the steps...

Comment: you wrote the steps, need to focus on each and get them working

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reason to use lambda function to spin ECS task ?

Can you not use lambda function to write files directly to S3 bucket.